# Computationally Intensive Ruby Calc for Rails App - Extract to Pure Ruby & Filesystem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, activerecord

Good afternoon,

I am developing a Rails application where I can vastly speed up the site by doing a bunch of pre-calculations and storing the results to the database, rather than performing the calculation when requested by the user.

(Note that I am talking about millions of iterations from hundreds of thousands of database rows.  My estimation is that to complete all of the calculations I could do, it will take about 4 days on my Macbook Air.)

My question is this:
Would there be any benefit in stripping these calculations out of the Rails / ActiveRecord framework, and complete it all using pure ruby code and no database?  Is File I/O going to be just as much of a bottleneck when writing out the results?  How would you approach this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I think is that if you have time consuming computing to do you should move away not only from rails but also from ruby. Ruby is incredibly slow compared to C or C++. So I would use them and let them store their results in the db(or in some other place reachable by your rails application). Then rails can just read the results. If it's a viable option for you, you might consider using db procedures, if you are on a SQL db that is. Those will be much faster than the same algo in ruby.

Then of course it's up to you to figure out when to trigger the (re-)computation. Either time-based cron trigger or based on the conditions in your system.

Comment: Thanks for the input Renra.  I was afraid that might be the answer :)  The only issue is that I don't know any C or enough SQL to write stored procedures without some serious research.  I suppose I might have to bite the bullet...